# Angular reference error $scope not defined

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to angular and I am trying to list my data in database .However I am gettin $scope not defined error..This is my code

```
 productsService
           .getProducts()
           .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

               $scope.products = data;

               console.log($scope.products);
           })
           .error(function (error) {
               //Showing error message 
               $scope.status = 'Unable to retrieve product' + error.message;
           });
```

In my product Service I have

```
return {
            getProducts: function () {

                return $http({
                    method: 'GET',                        
                    url: '/api/Products'
                }).success(function (data) {
                    alert("success");
                   // console.log(data);
                }).error(function (error) {
                    //Showing error message 
                    alert("failed");
                    $scope.status = 'Unable to retrieve products' + error.message;
                    console.log($scope.status);
                });

            },
```

I am just getting failed alert. Please help!!!In backend I am able to get the data from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an Angular service, you do not have access to the `$scope`, that is something you only have in directives and controllers. That is why you are getting an error about `$scope` being undefined.

Also, in your service you are returning a promise from your `getProducts()` method, yet you are also adding success and error handlers on to it. You should make up your mind whether you want to return the raw `$http` promise, or if instead you want to return a `$q` promise which is resolved with some transformed copy of the data returned in the `$http().success()` handler.

One final thing, if you are seeing the "failed" alert, that means your server is returning an error when you submit a request to `/api/Products`. If you go to that URL in your browser, does it work? You should look into why a basic GET request to that URL is not working.

Comment: i tried directly accessing the api/products and I am getting some error which I have no clue of Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace/>

Answer (score 1):

You should not uses scope variables in your service, you service should only be used to get/update/share some data.

Here is how your service should look like

**Service**

```
return {
    getProducts: function() {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/api/Products'
        });
    },
```

and in your controller for that service method you can have a `.success()` and `.error()` which you can use to set your error messages.

**Controller**

```
productsService
   .getProducts()
   .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
       $scope.products = data;
   })
   .error(function (error) {
       $scope.status = 'Unable to retrieve product' + error.message;
   });
```

Hope this helps.